# Development of Chat Room using Openfire for IPhone

Tags: ios

If you have any idea or link for the development for chat room using Openfire for IPhone, can you share to you?
I really need this knowledge urgently.

Comment: Did you start by looking at their website? http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/